# get back the last updated data from local storage

Tags: angularjs

i want to retrieve my last updated value from local storage.
my code is:

```
 $scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('ids');
 $scope.ids = JSON.parse($scope.saved);
 localStorage.setItem('ids', JSON.stringify($scope.ids));

 console.log($scope.ids)

 $scope.LogIn = function() {
 if($scope.id=='1'){
 $state.go('app.playlists');
 }

 $scope.ids = [];
 $scope.ids.push({text:$scope.id});

     localStorage.setItem('ids', JSON.stringify($scope.ids));
```

};

using this code i am not getting the value in console instead getting 'undefined'[image]

Comment: DOn't ask same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$scope.ids.length-1` to get the last index of the array

```
$scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('ids');
$scope.ids = JSON.parse($scope.saved);

console.log($scope.ids[$scope.ids.length-1])
```